# Performance loss when using UNION ALL to add an arbitrary tuple

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to add an arbitrary tuple to a `SELECT` result containing 1.8M rows. I decided to use the `UNION` operator like this :

```
SELECT 
    id as id
FROM 
    user
UNION
SELECT 
    -1 as id
```

Which returns :

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
| -1|
+---+
| 01|
+---+
| 02|
+---+
|...|
+---+
```

However the performance loss between the queries with and without the `UNION` operator is tremendous. I tried using a `UNION ALL` statement like this :

```
SELECT 
    id as id
FROM 
    user
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    -1 as id
```

Which - I thought - could have been the reason behind the perf loss but the performance impairment is still there.

Am I missing something ? I simply want to add an extra arbitrary tuple to the `SELECT` result.

Comment: What are you going to do with 1 800 001 rows with id values? Lots of data...

Comment: @jarlh Aha true! My question is a hack I tried while working on a big set of data and couldn't understand why it behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) appears to result in a temporary table being created. See this [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50674) for reference.

Creating a temporary table with 1.8M rows is likely the cause of your slowdown.

In good news, 5.7.3 appears to change this behavior in some situations. See last post in the linked bug report.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the information. I am running my query against a MySQL 5.6 so that must be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `union all` instead of `union`.  `union` removes duplicates:

```
SELECT id as id
FROM user
UNION ALL
SELECT -1 as id
```

If `-1` could be a valid value -- and you only want it to appear once -- then you can do:

```
SELECT id as id
FROM user
UNION ALL
SELECT u.id
FROM (SELECT -1 as id) u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE user.id = u.id)
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I tried using `UNION ALL` but there's still a huge performance impairment compared to the query without this operator.

Comment: @Simon . . . The query in your question uses `UNION` not `UNION ALL`.  And, your return set *strongly* suggests that you are using `union` and not `union all`.

Comment: Oh you're right, my mistake. I wrote "I thought" while I actually tried `UNION ALL` but didn't observe any significant performance improvement. I'll edit my question to clarify the step I took.